# Check if the file has been successfully transferred to the destination with SFTP

Tags: aix, ftp, sftp

We have a daily process which moves file from 1 server to another via FTP using a script. Please find the snippet below:

```sh
fileTransferToDEST()
{
ftp -inv $DEST_IP 1>$2 <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $SRV_USER
quote PASS $SRV_PASS
lcd $4
cd $3
bi
prompt
hash
mput $1
quit
END_SCRIPT
}

fileTransferToDEST $filename $logpathwithfilename $destinationpath $sourcepath

returnvalue=$?

FtpStatus=`grep "Transfer complete" $logpathwithfilename`

if [ "$FtpStatus" = '' -o "$returnvalue" != "0" ]; then

                echo;echo "FTP : Failed while transfering"
                exit 2

fi
```

I have been assigned to convert the FTP script to use SFTP. I have successfully finished all the necessary steps to have passwordless login in SFTP. please find the script using SFTP below:

```sh
fileTransferToDEST()
{
sftp $SRV_USER@$DEST_IP 1>$2 <<END_SCRIPT
lcd $4
cd $3
mput $1
quit
END_SCRIPT
}

fileTransferToDEST $filename $logpathwithfilename $destinationpath $sourcepath

returnvalue=$?

FtpStatus=`grep "Transfer complete" $logpathwithfilename`

if [ "$FtpStatus" = '' -o "$returnvalue" != "0" ]; then

                echo;echo "FTP : Failed while transfering"
                exit 2

fi
```

However I am unable to check/find how to successfully check if the file has 100% been transferred to the destination. How can I achieve this?

---

**Code after applying `-b` ...Based on answer..**

```sh
fileTransferToDEST()
{
echo "mput $4/$1 $3/" | sftp -b - $SRV_USER@$DEST_IP
}

fileTransferToDEST $filename $logpathwithfilename $destinationpath $sourcepath

returnvalue=$?


if [ "$returnvalue" != "0" ]; then

                echo;echo "FTP : Failed while transfering"
                exit 2

fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH `sftp` indicates its results using an exit code (what you are going already).

If it returns 0, everything went fine. If it returns 1, there was a problem.

No need to parse the output for an arbitrary message.

Just execute it in a batch mode, so that it aborts on any error. Use [`-b -` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#b) for that (the `-` indicates that you still want to provide the commands using stdin, not via a file, which would normally follow the `-b`).

Comment: `FtpStatus=...` line should have been removed as well.